# DLL making and linking in C

Tags: c, dll, header

i was trying to make a dll in C, so i found this:

http://forum.codecall.net/topic/47543-how-to-create-and-use-dll-in-c/#gsc.tab=0

i followed the last post, but i always end up having this error whenever i use the function "sum" in a client file:

[Error] C:\Users\Siegfred\Desktop\dll testing\test.c:7: undefined reference to `*imp*_sum'

NOTES: A. im using MinGW 5 in an IDE named C-free. B. after i compile the header and the c file for the dll, the IDE/compiler looks for an .exe which is not generated.

how do i fix this? thank you.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But i feel spaces in path names `dll testing` should be avoided.

Comment: that's a folder name.